# Using a multiplication or addition operation in writing the table for $Z_{13} = Z/13 Z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

The question I am trying to answer is shown below:

> [image]

And I know that the answer requires me to find the reduced row echelon form of the following matrix :

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 4
 \\
8 & 3 & 10 & 5 & 12
 \\
7 & 6 & 2 & 11 & 7
& p_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But I do not know when I have an entry 2 in the matrix and I want to make it 1, so I want to multiply by its inverse, shall I put its inverse according to the multiplication table or the addition table of $\mathbb{Z_{13}}$? or it does not matter?

Comment: Multiply the elements in the row by $7$.

Comment: Why precisely $7$ @stevengregory ? why multiplication table and not addition table

Comment: is it because the scalar multiplication of the field @stevengregory

Comment: Because $7 \cdot 2 = 1$ in $\mathbb Z_{13}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous system of linear equations can be written $Ax=0$ for some matrix $A$ and $x\in \Bbb F_{13}^5$. We can think of this as a map $f\colon \Bbb F_{13}^5\to \Bbb F_{13}^5$ where $f(x)=Ax$. Then the desired set of solutions to the equation is exactly $\ker f$, which is the same as the null space of $A$.

First let's simplify the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ given. We may row reduce the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 4\\
8 & 3 & 10 & 5 & 12\\
7 & 6 & 2 & 11 & 7
\end{pmatrix}$$

to obtain

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 6\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 10 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 11 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.$$

This is the desired null space of our matrix $A$. The main point is that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are indeed linearly independent, so the set $v_1,v_2,v_3,e_4,e_5$ is a basis of $\Bbb F_{13}^5$, where $e_4=(0,0,0,1,0)$ and $e_5=(0,0,0,0,1)$. In this basis, the desired matrix is just

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Presumably we want to express $B$ in the standard basis. The change of basis matrix is

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 10 & 11 & 1 & 0\\
6 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus $A=PBP^{-1}$. The rest is computational.

Comment: in the second matrix (you obtained from row reduction ... in the 7th line) you calculated it using the multiplication table of $F$ or the addition table of $F$?

Comment: I'm don't really understand the question. When you add two numbers together, use the additive structure; when you multiply them, use the multiplicative structure.

Comment: I did not get the same reduced row echelon form as you, the last 2 entries in the second row of mine are 3 and 9, and the last two entries in the third row of mine are 6 and 1.

Comment: I am not sure what is the importance of the change of basis matrix? I think the reduced row echelon form is for $A^t$ and not $A$ so you just take the transpose and you will be done